# How to turn on generating the debug info?

Tags: c++, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Debug symbols information is missing from my node built from cpp file with catkin_make in hydro. I need it to debug the node with the gdb. How to turn on generating the debug info?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/169846/how-to-turn-on-generating-the-debug-info?/) by [sd](https://answers.ros.org/users/15166/sd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you build the package from source you might want to set the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to either Debug or RelWithDebInfo (see http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) when invoking cmake:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2